# When opening Visual Studio it wants me to Modify, Repair or Uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I had Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86) installed in my computer originally and I installed the Community Edition 2013 Update 4 from here: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#DownloadFamilies_2.

When it finished installing it worked OK, then I closed it, and when I re-opened , it wanted me to Modify, Repair or Uninstall (couldn't bypass it). I chose Repair, but when I close and re-open it again, it does the same and I can't seem to launch Visual Studio.

Any direction to solving this? 
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're opening an installer, not the editor exe

Comment: Ok, that's definitely possible.
In which folder should I look for the editor?

Comment: Eh, don't recall exactly off the top of my head, but it's something like `Program Files\MSVC10\Common\IDE`

Answer (score 2):

Go through similar to this path on your machine `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv` (open devenv) and directly open `devenv` application it won't give you any error about modify repair uninstall